# Make share URLs of questions and answers use HTTPS by default or based on loading protocol

Tags: feature-request, security, ssl, sharing

I like to visit sites via HTTPS if possible and use HTTPS Everywhere to enforce. I was pretty surprised to see that links that I copied from the "share" box didn't use HTTPS but only HTTP.

This could be confirmed for different questions and answers on Stack Overflow.

I request that the share URL contains HTTPS if I used HTTPS to visit Stack Overflow — or even better: always present share URLs with HTTPS.

Comment: I believe this is because SE still isn't entirely SSL, and thus implying it was (by putting `https` on links by default) would be misleading - see e.g. http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/